# A word that means "presenting something without context"

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms, colloquialisms

I think there is a word that means something is presented or said without context, like a statement that appears random. "Leftfield statement" comes close, but I think there's something more concise.

Some people malapropriate "non sequitur" for meaning this. (I'm basically looking for the word that means what those people think "non sequitur" means.)

I'll give an example of what I would describe with the word we're looking for:
Someone on Twitter posts the message: "Oh, not this again…”
No context (e.g. in previous tweets), completely leftfield.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Why is it not *malapropism* itself?

Comment: @Kris: "malapropism" is a term that means something different than the user thinks it does. The word I'm looking for describes something the user understands fully; it's the reader that's left in the dark.

Comment: I'm not convinced that *non sequitur* is wrong here. Its literal meaning is "it does not follow", which perfectly describes the lack of context. Is your objection to it simply that it's also the name of a logical fallacy?

Comment: Have you checked the word in a good dictionary?

Comment: Why do you keep using *leftfield* if that's not what it is? The example sentence and its context are not examples of *leftfield*. Nor is it *non sequitur*.

Comment: The example sentence and its context should be adequate and enough to explain the question. Everything else is a distraction and diversion from the point. Can you edit the post?

Comment: @Kris: "leftfield" alone only describes the statement, not that it _is_ a statement. The example is not quite enough; I want to make sure the word captures the nuance and has the connotations I'm looking for.

Comment: All the more reason why we should avoid using those words that are not quite the answer.

Comment: @jsheeran: A non sequitur requires previous statements… context. I'm looking for something that is completely detached from any context.

Comment: @Kris: Is it not useful to gather as much relevant meaning as we can? Won't our neurons fire in response to related neurons being active?

Comment: The lack of any previous statements *is* the context in which the statement doesn't follow.

Comment: @jsheeran I agree with Protector One. `non sequitur` can't really be applicable if *nothing* was said previously.

Comment: “Not so much of a question, more of a comment actually...”

Comment: On social media, the coinage "vaguebooking" describes posted/tweeted exclamations about undivulged topics. https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/imbecilic-art-vaguebooking/

Comment: @Protectorone Please edit you question and add an example of how you intend to use the word you are looking for (a sample sentence, as explained in the `single-word-requests` tag).

Comment: @Protectorone I don't understand why you think that **non sequitur** is the *wrong* term.. In a comment you say that it "requires previous statements" but that's false. Here's one of its [definitions](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/non%20sequitur): "a statement (such as a response) that does not follow logically from or is not clearly related to anything previously said." It sounds like a perfectly appropriate term to me. If you're really talking about something said completely out of the blue, that's nothing more than an **interjection**.

Comment: I believe you are contradicting yourself? Doesn't "anything previously said" imply previous statements?

Comment: related - [out of the blue](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28804/meaning-and-best-case-usage-of-out-of-the-blue)

Comment: related - [A word which describes a statement or question that is vague or random](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/479755/a-word-which-describes-a-statement-or-question-that-is-vague-or-random)

Comment: related - [Opposite of a rhetorical statement](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/347363/244156)

Answer (score 1):

We don't know what `this` is referring to. The intention of holding the context back is forcing others to ask or attempting a dramatic reveal.

This is called "(playing) **the pronoun game**". It's not a standard expression yet, but common enough on the internet.

> Using pronouns in dialogue to force other characters to ask for an explanation or conceal info

-- [TVtropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/discussion.php?id=b4pcb4ytjt235ec4b03cjekt)

> "playing the pronoun game" is when a character uses a pronoun such as "he" or "they" in place of a name forcing another character to ask "who?". Often used in films to give an excuse for exposition or as a cheap way to add mystery.
>
> A: He's coming.
>
> B: Who? Who's coming? You can't just say "he" and expect everyone to know who you're talking about. Don't play the pronoun game with me.

-- [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=the%20pronoun%20game)

---

Be advised that "the pronoun game" might also refer to the act of avoiding gender-specific pronouns like `he` or `she` in order to obscure personal information.

Comment: Interesting! I quite like it.

Answer (score -1):

A possible word choice here is **impertinent**.

https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/impertinent

It’s a good starting point, because its meaning in English has shifted over time from *irrelevant* to *insolent* and now (partly) back to *irrelevant* again. As a result, it has picked up an impressive collection of synonyms.

Thesaurus.com leans towards the *insolent* meaning, but from there you can broaden out to other words.

https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/impertinent