# A word which describes a statement or question that is vague or random

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, american-english

I'm looking for that word which people use to describe very random out of the blue *questions.

You say the most (???) things?

Comment: Are you looking for *non sequitur*?

Comment: Jim (no but that's a good word). People say it when something is particularly random or strange, almost meaningless. Like a vague unanswerable question that can't have an answer delibrately. It's just out there for interpretation.

Comment: I think it ends it (ate). I'm just trying the forum but I'll close the question myself otherwise.

Comment: Maybe *inane*?  You say the most inane things.

Comment: I think this should be reopened because I asked for a word of which I do not know..hence you're limited in the description and it's been up voted and has some helpful responses of which those who flagged the post have offered ZERO

Answer (score 1):

I would either use **random**, as you've suggested yourself, "the most **unexpected**", or "the **weirdest** things". "The **wildest**" might also work, depending on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

I think "peculiar".

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peculiar)

peculiar

adjective

: different from the usual or normal:

Comment: NB: If you quote someone else's words, it's essential that you make this clear (eg using quotation marks or blockquote formatting) and **acknowledge the source** (preferably with a link). It's not only polite to give the original author credit, it also avoids the more serious charge of *plagiarism*. I urge you to [edit] your post accordingly.

Comment: This is not an answer according to our standards here because it contains no reasoning or explanation in your own words. Please read [this advice from SE’ss Community Management team](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11731/2085) and update this with your content.  We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Comment: Updated my answer.